# The resizableColumns of Primefaces data table doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page which has a table with many columns. When I try to make the columns resizable, the result is very strange and is not the same for all browsers.

For FireFox, the first column ("ID" in the demonstration code) works fine. When you try to push the right boundary of the second column ("Book Name") to the left, its next column is enlaged on both sides. The rest columns only have a limited space to be enlarged.

For Chrome, the situation is more severe. The first column cannot be enlarged. The whole table width is actually shrinking when you try to enlarge the rest columns.

Microsoft Edge behaves more or less the same as FireFox.

I am using Primefaces 5.2 with JSF 2.2 (JavaEE 7) and use GlassFish 4.1 as a server. The development environment is NetBeans 8.0.2 with Bundled Maven 3.0.5.

I include the demonstration code for JSF and CSS, Does anyone know the solution, please help. Thanks in advance.

The JSF page:

```
    <h:head>
    <title>Data Table Format</title>                
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/datatable-format.css"/>          
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable styleClass="ui-datatable-hor-scroll" var="book" value="#{publishedBookView.books}" id="viewDataTable" paginator="true" rows="20"
                     paginatorTemplate="{Calendar} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" paginatorPosition="top">
            <f:facet name="{Calendar}">
                <p:outputLabel class="header-calendar">From Date</p:outputLabel>
                <p:calendar class="header-calendar" id="fromDate" value="#{book.publishDate}" pattern="dd MMM yyyy"  readonlyInput="true">
                  <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="viewDataTable" />
                </p:calendar>
                <p:outputLabel class="header-calendar">To Date</p:outputLabel>
                <p:calendar class="header-calendar" id="toDate" value="#{book.publishDate}" pattern="dd MMM yyyy" readonlyInput="true" >
                  <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="viewDataTable"/>
                </p:calendar>  
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
              <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage name="/img/excel.png" styleClass="exporter-button"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="viewDataTable" fileName="records" />
              </h:commandLink>
              <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage name="/img/csv.png" styleClass="exporter-button"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="viewDataTable" fileName="records" />
              </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="ID" class="book-id-format" sortBy="#{book.bookId}" filterBy="#{book.bookId}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.bookId}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="BOOK Name" class="book-name-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.bookName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 01" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>                
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 02" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 03" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>                
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 04" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 05" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>                
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 06" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 07" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>                
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 08" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 09" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>                
            <p:column headerText="Published Date 10" class="published-date-format">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishDate}" />
            </p:column>                                
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

The CSS sheet:

```
.book-id-format {
height: 8px !important;
margin-top: 3px !important;
width: 180px;}

.book-name-format {
height: 8px !important;
margin-top: 3px !important;
min-width: 80px;}

.published-date-format {
height: 8px !important;
margin-top: 3px !important;
width: 80px;}

.ui-datatable-hor-scroll .ui-datatable-tablewrapper,.scrolling-div .ui-datatable-tablewrapper{
overflow: auto;
width: auto;}

.ui-datatable.ui-widget {
font-size: 50%;}

.ui-paginator {
font-size: x-small;
width: auto;
height: 26px;}

.exporter-button {
float: right;
width: 24px;
margin-right: 5px;
background: none;}

.header-calendar {
float: left;  
margin-right: 5px;}

.ui-datepicker {  
background: white;
font-size: 70%;}
```

Comment: Please create an  [mcve], see also http://www,stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info (e.g. what is the relevance of the css?). And try the latest version (many things are fixed between 5.2 and 5.3 as can be read in the issuelist, blog etc)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your comment. The code is a complete example for people to reproduce. It is a bit lengthy since the table is wide. I can remove some lines when I have time. I cannot use 5.3 at the moment.

Comment: I said TRY 5.3 (just to see if something is fixed in the meantime) I nowhere stated you should use it in production. If it does not work in 5.2 and does in 5.3 then you can use the source of 5.3 to see how to fix this with a patch in 5.2. Cause things like this are so complex that there is no simple solution and I doubt people create patches for things like this let alone share it). And **knowing** it is fixed is knowledge that can be shared...

Comment: 5.3 has the same behaviour as 5.2.

Comment: I took a little look at your question again in combination with the answer. One of the most important reasons it 'does not work properly' is that you mess with the css of the datatable to make it scrollable. The datatable has a scrollable option. You in addition use css to define column size, which is not advised to. So the answer below 'fixes' something that you broke. Try starting from scratch and you'll most likely see it working without all the css stuff

Comment: thanks for the reply. This code is only for the demonstration. The real code is more complex. The column sizes has to be fixed and resizable for each column due to the requirement. The table has to be scrollable as well. I know the design is ugly but I have no power to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a full difination for the column width in CSS, it may work all right:

```
.book-name-format {
height: 8px !important;
margin-top: 3px !important;
width: 80px;
min-width: 80px;
max-width: 200px;
}
```